# How can I hide filter options in an accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Let's use this codepen for example: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nFrte

What if I wanted to hide the filtering options by toggling an .active class (that would display: block, vs display:none as default styling)?

When I do this on my own, the accordion is behind the isotope masonry layout. I would like the isotope masonry part to bump down.

I've tried:

```
$container.isotope('reloadItems').isotope('layout');
```

After I toggle the class.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the accordion is behind the isotope masonry layout", but I made this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yukzf

Comment: @Mardoxx, thanks for this, it helped me solve my issue.